# How do you write a main method to start a java program?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, main-method

I'm a beginner programmer and am tasked to write an inventory program.
I have only programmed using BlueJay so far, but am about to learn how to use the vim editor.
When programming with BlueJay, you didn't need to write a main method.
I'm so lost about how to write the main method and everything I researched over the internet didn't seem to explain or help much.

I have already started the design of the program where I have an Inventory class and an Item class.
How would I go about starting this project?  Like what do I need to do with the main method and how would that work?

Thanks

Here is the code I have so far.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Inventory
{
    private ArrayList<Item>inventory;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Inventory
     */
    public Inventory()
    {
        inventory = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

    /**
     * Adds an Item to the Inventory.
     */
    public void addItem(String name, int amount, double price, int location)
    {
        boolean done = false;
        if(inventory.size() == 0)
        {
            inventory.add(new Item(name, amount, price, location));
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; (!done)&&(i < inventory.size()); i++)
            {
                if(inventory.get(i).getName().equals(name))
                {
                    System.out.println("Item name in use. Please use another name.");
                    done = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    inventory.add(new Item(name, amount, price, location));
                    done = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an Item from the Inventory.
     */
    public void deleteItem(String name)
    {
        ...........
    }

    /**
     * Search for an Item.
     */
    public void searchItem(String name)
    {
        ...........
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/

Comment: I LOVE vim - but I think for Java coding you're probably much better off with a Java IDE like Intellij or Eclipse which will give you a lot of hints about what might be wrong with your code.

Comment: Yeah, but I have to use it for this class I'm in.

Comment: Also, I've already looked at the oracle tutorial and I'm still stuck without understanding how to move on from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are answers for this everywhere in Java documentation. But here it is.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        //start here
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that part, but what should go where the "start here" is?
I asked the question more so for the design purpose.  What is actual supposed to be in the main method?

Comment: @DaveMcFave - what you want your program to actually do goes into the main method. You said you have an Inventory class and an Item class. I don't know what either of them do, but perhaps instantiating them would be a good start. `Inventory myInventory = new Inventory();`.

Comment: So, would I just write all the methods I want the client to be able to use in the main method? For example, the constructor and the mutating methods?

Comment: @DaveMcFave - Check out the Getting Started tutorial that was linked in your question as it goes through step-by-step what Hello World does and how it works. I also suggest going back to your instructor and getting them to explain the fundamentals of how a program works in Java (and in general).